# Takes several minutes to run SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I have pretty simple SSRS report, it takes less then 1 second to run stored procedure. The report works just fine when I upload it on local server. However on remote server (SQL Server 2012) it takes 5-7 minutes to run report. Other my reports on remote server work good. Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your local DB and remote SQL Server 2012 DB are the same ? (same data ?)

Comment: Yes, i have a "fresh" copy of DB on my local mashine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use SQL Profiler or ReportServer DB to check which process is slow.
you can use this SQL for checking:

```
USE ReportServer
SELECT ReportPath,
       RequestType,
       Format,
       ReportAction,
       TimeDataRetrieval,
       TimeProcessing,
       TimeRendering,
       DATEDIFF(S, TimeStart, TimeEnd) AS TotalSeconds
FROM ExecutionLog2
```

Where TimeDataRetrieval is a time of stored procedure execution + sending time to ReportServer, TimeProcessing - it's time spent for grouping, sorting etc. in report side and TimeRendering is time spent for rendering.

Then when you know why execution is slow - you can thinking about ways of fixing (fix stored procedure, add indexes, change report structure etc.).

I had such problem which cause parameters sniffing  ([about parameters sniffing](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/)), to prevent this you shouldn't use your input parameters in your query like follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_MySP] @InputValue INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SomeValue INT;
    SET @SomeValue = @InputValue;

    SELECT SomeColumn 
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE SomeColumn = @SomeValue
END
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. You wrote: "to prevent this you shouldn't use your input parameters in your query like follows" ,,,, Could you advise what one should do instead, in particular for reports that require a dropdown for the user to select a parameter value? Thanks again.